# How to initialize act to something without making it null

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HealthValueInput extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private AccountManager act;
//  private ArrayList<Account> temp;
//  private int count = 0;

    /** Creates new form HealthValueInput */
    public HealthValueInput() {
        initComponents();
        
        //count++;
        PopulateArrayList();
        save();
        //act = new AccountManager(temp.get(count));
    }

    public AccountManager getACT() {
        return act;
    }

    private void save() {
        try {
            FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("accountmanager.dat");
            ObjectOutputStream y = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
            for (int k = 0; k < act.getAccounts().size(); k++) {
                y.writeObject(act.getAccounts().get(k));
            }

            y.close();
            this.dispose();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("something wrong with save");
        }
    }

    private void PopulateArrayList() {
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("accountmanager.dat");
            ObjectInputStream inputFile = new ObjectInputStream(file);
            
            boolean x = false;
            while (!x) {
                try {
                    act.getAccounts().add((Account)inputFile.readObject());
                } catch(EOFException e) {
                    x = true;
                } catch(Exception F) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, F.getMessage());
                }
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if (jTextField1.getText().isEmpty() || jTextField2.getText().isEmpty() || jTextField3.getText().isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill all fields");
        } else {
            double height = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText().trim());
            double weight = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText().trim());
            int age = Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText().trim());
            //this is a string
            char gender = jComboBox1.getItemAt(0).charAt(0);
            System.out.println(gender);
            
            HealthCalculations h = new HealthCalculations(height, weight, age, gender);
            NamesPasswords z = new NamesPasswords();
            
            Account a = new Account(h, z.getUser().get(act.getAccounts().size() - 1), z.getLogin().get(act.getAccounts().size() - 1));
            
            act.getAccounts().add(a);
        }
        
        save();
        this.dispose();
        new LoginPage().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It used to work when I only used an array list inside the jframe and didn't make classes AccountManager and Accounts. I have been trying to shift more code out of the jframe classes but ended up with this mess. The program refuses to open this jframe when run because it says can't invoke Packages.AccountManager.getAccounts() because this.act is null. Please help I'm literally dog water at java.

Comment: Perhaps start your PopulateArrayList method with `act = new AccountManager();`?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the dependency in the constructor:

```
    private final AccountManager act;

    public HealthValueInput(AccountManager accountManager) {
      this.act = accountManager;
      ...
    }
```